# Bootstrap datepicker in TypeScript is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I am a newbie to `Angular 4` and I am trying to make a sort of `jQuery` call from my HTML. I have tried wrapping this `jQuery` call in a `TypeScript` method. **Upon clicking the calendar button nothing appears**.

I am unsure what line to exactly add in my `index.html`.

Below is my code snippet :

**home.component.html**

```
<h2>As of date</h2>
<div class="input-group" style="width: 230px">
    <input class="form-control date" type='text' placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="date-picker"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" (click)="pickDate()">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { TasksService } from 'app/shared';


        @Component({
          selector: 'MyFirstAngularApplication-home',
          styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
          templateUrl: './home.component.html'
        })

        export class HomeComponent {
          pickDate() {
            $('#date-picker').datepicker('show');
          }
        }
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Check this, https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: @Reinhardt, I know of the solution you attached and have tried it as well. But I want a very specific look and feel for my calendar.

Comment: Then check your css

Answer (score 0):

1. Import `jquery.min.js` in `home.component.html` .
2. In home.component.ts declare **jquery** and **$** vars like:

   declare var jquery:any;
   declare var $ :any;

You should be through now

Comment: How do I import something into an HTML file?With a script tag?

Comment: Because my index.html already has the following line :                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: that's good , have you added the var(s) in home.component.ts which I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yes added everything. Still not working. Upon clicking nothing happens. I do F12 on the webpage and I get datepicker isn't a function

Comment: meaning it is not picking up jquery ,  can you change the script file name to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js  and see if it works

Comment: Nope still not working. jQuery does have such a function right?

Comment: Same error stating that datepicker isn't a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158928/discussion-between-satya-and-abhijeet-mohanty).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Before added needs to be installed jquery in angular project via command like

npm install jquery

**Index.Html**

```
<script src="assets/Scripts/Jquery3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
<script src="assets/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">   
<script src="assets/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TasksService } from 'app/shared';
declare var $: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'MyFirstAngularApplication-home',
      styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
      templateUrl: './home.component.html'
    })

    export class HomeComponent {
      pickDate() {
        $("#date-picker").datepicker();            
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I have done to install jQuery. Though in my assets folder, I do not have those files to be included.

Comment: just added those files in assets folder manually what are the script files needed, by installation it has to be defined the some more library files in angular project